# Cut and Paste not working in Datasheet view Sharepoint 2013 O365

Tags: 2013, office-365, excel, datasheet, copy-and-paste

I have a question regarding an unusual error that I can't seem to resolve.  I have a document library and am trying to cut and paste metadata from an excel 2013 spreadsheet into columns in a datasheet view, and after hitting Ctrl+V, this is what happens:

1. I am sometimes prompted by an alert window asking me if I want to allow access to clipboard (sometimes not); I select "allow access"
2. The list goes entirely white (data disappears)
3. The page refreshes, and the data returns, EXCEPT what I pasted is not present.

I've tried pasting multiple times (an absurd number of times really), cleansing my excel data to plain text, changing the fields I'm pasting into (they are single lines of text, should be forgiving to the extreme), I've done this thousands of times before on other lists/libraries, but for some reason this library, this data--nothing!  Any help/advice would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Comment: What browser are you using? If you're using Edge try using IE instead.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what  type of fileds You are trying to paste into i guess the reason can be that If the Columns are of the type "Managed Metadata" the values must exist in Term Store, otherwise the will be considered as not valid.

Comment: Thanks Magnus, but it isn't an issue where the data is being entered and then SP balks at the type/format/etc.  I simply cannot paste _anything_ into the datasheet view on this list.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the field in grayed out, so maybe the problem because of "Edit (link to edit item)" column, try to unchecked this column from your view, and then it should work.